# Emberjs: stop and retry transitions in willTransition

Tags: javascript, ember.js, transition

When a user is about to leave the present route, I'd like to display a warning and let him choose between leaving (and losing changes) and staying in the current route.

In order to catch all possible transitions, I need to do this in the routes `willTransition` method.

I'm attempting to `abort()` and then `retry()` the transition if the user chooses to. But the `retry` doesn't seem to have any effect. It should be noted that it is called asynchronously. Here's a twiddle that demonstrates that: https://ember-twiddle.com/b6d8ddb665ff79f2988277912916e77b?openFiles=routes.my-route.js%2C

Here's my route example route:

```html
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  actions: {
    willTransition(transition) {
      transition.abort();
      Ember.run.later(function(){
        console.log('Transition... now!');
        transition.retry();
      }, 2000);

      return true;
    }
  }
});
```

The log shows up, but I never get redirected to the `application` route.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look into log. You will see that "Transition... now!" appears there every 2 sec. That shows that `willTransition` works again and again. So you need some flag that allows you to go away. [Updated twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/609845399f6925bce09571b536198069?openFiles=routes.my-route.js%2C)

Comment: Well caught! I should have seen the log kept on coming :) Thanks.

Comment: I just didn't realized that transition.retry() calls the function willTransition() again. Thanks for your example!

Answer (score 1):

When a user is about to leave the present route, I'd like to display a warning and let him choose between leaving (and losing changes) and staying in the current route.
For the above requirement, the below code is enough.

```
willTransition(transition) {
    if (!confirm('Are you sure to navigate ?')) {
        transition.abort();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: The warning is made through a third party library (sweet-alert) which requires the confirmation to be asynchronous, hence why I wrote "It should be noted that it is called asynchronously."